# Elasticsearch group by ranges of time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a large dataset in which I need to group values based on the created_at time.

Requirements are that they're grouped by **5 minute intervals**.

I think that this should do it, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
self.search(aggs: {created_at: {date_histogram: {field: 'created_at', interval: 
'5m'}}})
```

This is the search query:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/prices_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":
{"match_all":{}},"size":1000,"from":0,"aggs":{"created_at":{"date_histogram":
{"field":"created_at","interval":"5m"}}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false}'
```

It just gives me back the entire set of data though. i.e. every record:

[image: rails console]

How can I to get back the data set, grouped by 5 minutes intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation results are present in `aggregations`field of the response, not `hits`.

Set `size` inside `aggs` to limit number of aggregations.

If you only want aggregation results then set outer `size` to `0`